# Moment js Calendar Time from unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

These are moment js calendar output (from the momentjs website)

```
moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar(); // 10/27/2017
moment().subtract(6, 'days').calendar();  // Last Tuesday at 9:10 PM
moment().subtract(3, 'days').calendar();  // Last Friday at 9:10 PM
moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();  // Yesterday at 9:10 PM
moment().calendar();                      // Today at 9:10 PM
moment().add(1, 'days').calendar();       // Tomorrow at 9:10 PM
moment().add(3, 'days').calendar();       // Thursday at 9:10 PM
```

I want to get same format output from my unix timestamp. 
I tried `moment().unix(1509982956).calendar();`, but that gives me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`moment.unix`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/):

> To create a moment from a Unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch), use `moment.unix(Number)`.

```js
console.log( moment.unix(1509982956).calendar() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

instead of [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) that is only a getter function.

> `moment#unix` outputs a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch).